# Crossover of two binary representations

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm trying to get a quick implementation of the following problem, ideally such that it would work in a numba function. The problem is the following: I have two random integers `a` & `b` and consider their binary representation of length `L`, e.g.

`L=4: a=10->1010`, `b=6->0110`.

This is the information that is feed into the function. Then I cut both binary representations in two at the same random position and fuse one of the two results, e.g.

`L=4: a=1|010`, `b=0|110` ---> c=`1110` or `0010`.

One of the two outcome is chosen with equal probability and that is the outcome of the function. The cut occurs between the first 1/0 and the last 0/1 of the binary representation.

This is currently my code:

```
def func(a,b,l):
    bin_a = [int(i) for i in str(bin(a))[2:].zfill(l)]
    bin_b = [int(i) for i in str(bin(b))[2:].zfill(l)]
    randint = random.randint(1, l - 1)
    print("randint", randint)
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        result = bin_a[0:randint]+bin_b[randint:l]
    else:
        result = bin_b[0:randint] + bin_a[randint:l]
    return result
```

I have the feeling that there a possibly many shortcuts to this problem that I do not come up with. Also my code does not work in numba :/. Thanks for any help!

**Edit**: This is an update of my code, thanks to Prunes help! It also works as a numba function. If there is no further improvements to that, I would close the question.

```
def func2(a,b,l):
    randint = random.randint(1, l - 1)
    print("randint", randint)

    bitlist_l = [1]*randint+[0]*(l-randint)
    bitlist_r = [0]*randint+[1]*(l-randint)
    print("bitlist_l", bitlist_l)
    print("bitlist_r", bitlist_r)
    l_mask = 0
    r_mask = 0
    for i in range(l):
        l_mask = (l_mask << 1) | bitlist_l[i]
        r_mask = (r_mask << 1) | bitlist_r[i]
    print("l_mask", l_mask)
    print("r_mask", r_mask)
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        c = (a & l_mask) | (b & r_mask)
    else:
        c = (b & l_mask) | (a & r_mask)
    return c
```

Comment: If you're not sure where the code is inefficient, then you need to profile it.
As this stands, the question is no longer appropriate for Stack Overflow; instead, it would go to StackExchange.CodeReview .... but read their posting guidelines first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve your code by realizing that you do not need a "human readable" binary representation to do binary operations.

For example, creating the mask:

```
m = (1<<randompos) - 1
```

The crossover can be done like so:

```
c = (a if coinflip else b) ^ ((a^b)&m)
```

And that's all.

Full example:

```
# create random sample
a,b = np.random.randint(1<<32,size=2)
randompos = np.random.randint(1,32)
coinflip = np.random.randint(2)
randompos
# 12
coinflip
# 0

# do the crossover
m = (1<<randompos) - 1
c = (a if coinflip else b) ^ ((a^b)&m)
 
# check
for i in (a,b,m,c):
    print(f"{i:032b}")
 
# 11100011110111000001001111100011
# 11010110110000110010101001111011
# 00000000000000000000111111111111
# 11010110110000110010001111100011
```

Comment: Oh wow, I understand. That really improved the computational time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You lose a *lot* of time converting between string and int.  Try bit operations instead.  Mask the items you want and construct the output without all the conversions.  Try these steps:

- size = [length of larger number in bits]  There are many ways to get this.
- Make a mask template, `size` 1-bits.
- Pick your random position, `pos`  `randint` is a poor anem, as it shadows the function you're using.
- Make two masks: l_mask = mask << pos; r_mask = mask >> pos.  This gives you two mutually exclusive and exhaustive bit-maps for your inputs.
- Flip your random coin, the 50-50 chance.  The < 0.5 result would be ...
- (a & l_mask) | (b & rmask)
- For the >= 0.5 result, switch `a` and `b` in that expression.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I skip the conversion? As I understand, a Mask is an boolean list/array, which I could apply to the binary list, but which I would still have to create?

Comment: A mask can be simply an int, `2^size-1`

Comment: Thanks, I have made an update to my post. I'm not sure whether there are still inefficiencies. Maybe you can have a look :)